# When I write the script in HTML file it works, when I put the same code in a js-file and link it it does not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I have run into a new problem in programming. I am trying to create a Quiz and I have written a script in the html file and it works perfectly. However, I want to separate the script from the html file and therefore I take the script code and put it into a js-document and link it to the index file. From my earlier experiences when doing this it has always worked without having to change anything. However, now I get an error message saying that the function checkAnswer is not defined!? Even though it is written in the js-document. Below is some of the code.

```
function _(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
    }

function renderQuestion() {
    test = _("test1");

    if(pos >= questions.length){
test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
_("testStatus").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
pos = 0;
correct = 0;
return false;
}
    _("testStatus").innerHTML = "Question " + (pos + 1)+ "of " + questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = question + "<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
    }

    function checkAnswer() {
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
if(choices[i].checked){
choice = choices[i].value;
}
}
if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
correct++;
}
pos++;
renderQuestion();
}
```

When I look in the console it seems like there is something wrong with the following row, but I can´t figure out how to fix it. It is when I press the submit answer button I get the error message.

```
test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
```

Thanks in advance!

Here is a link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zs860fLx/2/

The error message I get is "checkAnswer is not defined" on index.html row 1.

Comment: Did you check the network tab in the developer tools to see if the file is loaded in the first place? If it is loaded correctly but the error persists, Please post the HTML you used to include the js file. Also, please post the error message you got.

Comment: it's probably a path issue

Comment: I have uploaded a link to a JSfiddle and included the error message I get when running the code.

Comment: here this works : http://jsfiddle.net/zs860fLx/3/

Comment: Thanks! But what was it that you changed? I can´t notice any difference in the code!

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise your function. The easiest way to do this in plain javascript is to add an init function to your html file down at the bottom before your body closing tag.

```js
init = function() {
  doSomething();
};

doSomething = function() {
  console.log("yes");
}
```

```html
<body>

  
  <button onclick="doSomething()">click me</button>
  
  <script>
    (function() {
      init();
    })();
  </script>

</body>
```